# Change values of more than one text box (Based on ID or Input type)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am having more than 20 Text boxes with input type equals to number where in the `onload` process values will be set from data base retrieval. In this process there were instances where text box set values as "0.00". if the value equals to "0.00" I need to replace "0.00" with a blank. At current situation I have to check each an every text box value from id and assign blank manually. is there a way to speed up this process rather than below method I am trying  ?

**Method I am currently performing**

```js
//Currently values will be takn from DB Through JQuery Ajax Request

//Sample JSON Returning from DB 

var value = [["SME-00150","25.25","0.00",null,"0.00",null,"0.00",null,null,"0.00","0.00",null,"0.00","0.00",null,"0.00","0.00","0.00"]];


if (value[0][1] == "0.00") {
 document.getElementById('f3a1').value = "";
} else {
 document.getElementById('f3a1').value = value[0][1]
}


if (value[0][2] == "0.00") {
 document.getElementById('f3a2').value = "";
} else {
 document.getElementById('f3a2').value = value[0][2]
}



if (value[0][6] == "0.00") {
 document.getElementById('f3a3').value = "";
} else {
 document.getElementById('f3a3').value = value[0][6]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input id="f3a1" type="number"  placeholder="ValueOne"> 
  <input id="f3a2" type="number"  placeholder="ValueTwo"> 
  <input id="f3a3" type="number"  placeholder="ValueThree">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to replace all `0.00` values in the array with blank strings and then use that result array to fill the elements in your page:

```js
var value = [["SME-00150","25.25","0.00",null,"0.00",null,"0.00",null,null,"0.00","0.00",null,"0.00","0.00",null,"0.00","0.00","0.00"]];

var new_values = value.map(a => a.map(v => v == '0.00' ? '' : v));
console.log(new_values[0][1]);
document.getElementById('f3a1').value = new_values[0][1];
document.getElementById('f3a2').value = new_values[0][2];
document.getElementById('f3a3').value = new_values[0][6];
```

```html
<input id="f3a1">
<input id="f3a2">
<input id="f3a3">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Currently values will be takn from DB Through JQuery Ajax Request

//Sample JSON Returning from DB 

var value = [["SME-00150","25.25","0.00",null,"0.00",null,"0.00",null,null,"0.00","0.00",null,"0.00","0.00",null,"0.00","0.00","0.00"]];

if(value && value.length>0){
  value[0].foreach((val, i, arr)=>{
   let f3number = i+1;
   if (val == "0.00") {
      document.getElementById('f3a'+f3number).value = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('f3a'+f3number).value = val;
    }
  });
}


function clearNumberInputs(){
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]');
  for(let input of inputs){
    if(input.value == '0.00'){
      input.value = '';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input id="f3a1" type="number"  placeholder="ValueOne"> 
  <input id="f3a2" type="number"  placeholder="ValueTwo"> 
  <input id="f3a3" type="number"  placeholder="ValueThree">
  <button id="magic-buton" onclick='clearNumberInputs()'>clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the input `ids` dynamically and set the value if the value is not equal to `0.00`. For this you can use forEach loop.

Example

```js
   var value = [
["SME-00150", "25.25", "0.00", null, "0.00", null, "0.00", null, null, "0.00", "0.00", null, "0.00", "0.00", null, "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
];

value[0].forEach((val, index) => {
  document.getElementById("f3a" + (index + 1)).value = (val !== "0.00" ? val : '');
});
```

```html
    <input id="f3a1" type="number" placeholder="ValueOne">
    <input id="f3a2" type="number" placeholder="ValueTwo">
    <input id="f3a3" type="number" placeholder="ValueThree">
    <input id="f3a4" type="number" placeholder="ValueOne">
    <input id="f3a5" type="number" placeholder="ValueTwo">
    <input id="f3a6" type="number" placeholder="ValueThree">
    <input id="f3a7" type="number" placeholder="ValueOne">
    <input id="f3a8" type="number" placeholder="ValueTwo">
    <input id="f3a9" type="number" placeholder="ValueThree">
    <input id="f3a10" type="number" placeholder="ValueOne">
    <input id="f3a11" type="number" placeholder="ValueTwo">
    <input id="f3a12" type="number" placeholder="ValueThree">
    <input id="f3a13" type="number" placeholder="ValueOne">
    <input id="f3a14" type="number" placeholder="ValueTwo">
    <input id="f3a15" type="number" placeholder="ValueThree">
    <input id="f3a16" type="number" placeholder="ValueOne">
    <input id="f3a17" type="number" placeholder="ValueTwo">
    <input id="f3a18" type="number" placeholder="ValueThree">
```

Comment: this is not correct answer because he or she want do this in input set time not in click button